# Python remove null items from list

Tags: python, list, filter, null

I created the following list in python for `DynamoBIM`:

```
a = [["f", "o", "c"], [null, "o", null], [null, "o", null]]
```

I want to remove the null items from this list to create this list:

```
a = [["f", "o", "c"], ["o"], ["o"]]
```

I've attempted `list.remove(x)`, `filter`s, `for`-loops, and a number of other methods but cannot seem to get rid of these buggers.

How can I do this?

Comment: How nested are your lists?

Comment: What is `null`? You mean `None`?

Comment: Thank you everyone! These are all great answers; but this seems to be an issue with Dynamo. As @Arun points out, 'null' is not in Python. Dynamo creates these 'null' items in place of 'None' and they are somehow not recognizable as strings. If anyone runs into this issue while using Python in Dynamo, I used the 'Object.IsNull' and 'List.FilterByBoolMask' components to remove the 'null' items. ![Valid XHTML](http://tinypic.com/r/14dd6vq/8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Null is not in python, their it should be string like

```
list_value = [["f", "o", "c"], ['null', "o", 'null'], ['null', "o", 'null']]

[filter(lambda x: x!='null' and x!=None, inner_list) for inner_list in list_value]

[['f', 'o', 'c'], ['o'], ['o']]
```

You could also solve by nested list comprehension:

```
[[for i in inner_list if i!='null' and not i] for inner_list in list_value]
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you mean `None` by null, you can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> null = None
>>> nested_list = [["f", "o", "c"], [null, "o", null], [null, "o", null]]
>>> [[x for x in y if x] for y in nested_list]
[['f', 'o', 'c'], ['o'], ['o']]
```

In case null is some other value, you can alter the above to set the value of `null` as that something else, and alter the comprehension to:

```
>>> null = None # Replace with your other value
>>> [[x for x in y if x != null] for y in nested_list]
[['f', 'o', 'c'], ['o'], ['o']]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [["f", "o", "c"], [None, "o", None], [None, "o", None]]
l = []
for i in a:
    l.append(filter(lambda x: x is not None, i))

print (l)

[['f', 'o', 'c'], ['o'], ['o']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you meant `None`, you could try using the [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
a = [["f", "o", "c"], [None, "o", None], [None, "o", None]]
print [filter(None,x) for x in a]
```

---

```
>>> 
[['f', 'o', 'c'], ['o'], ['o']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [["f", "o", "c"], [None, "o", null], [null, "o", None]]
>>> a = [[sub for sub in item if sub] for item in a]
>>> a
[['f', 'o', 'c'], ['o'], ['o']]
>>>
```

This is equivalent to:

```
a = [["f", "o", "c"], [None, "o", null], [null, "o", None]]
new = []
for item in a:
    _temp = []
    for sub in item:
        if sub:
            _temp.append(sub)
    new.append(_temp)

a = new
```

---

```
>>> a = [["f", "o", "c"], [None, "o", null], [null, "o", None]]
>>> new = []
>>> for item in a:
...     _temp = []
...     for sub in item:
...         if sub:
...             _temp.append(sub)
...     new.append(_temp)
... 
>>> a = new
>>> a
[['f', 'o', 'c'], ['o'], ['o']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between "None" and NaN ("not a number") in Python, which is sometimes conventionally referred to as "null." The data type of NaN is generally a float. Therefore, if you are working with a list of only strings, as seems to be the case here, one idea is to filter for strings using a list comprehension.

```
a = ["f", "o", "c", np.nan]
b = [c for c in a if type(c)==str]
```